# Need to override both styling for MUIDatatable using latest Material UI v4 for the search input line unfocused/focused

Tags: search, overriding, styling, mui-datatable

I cannot seem to override the styling for this specific portion of the MUIDatatable.

I am unsure how to make this call and am new to react/material UI.

The block of code that it is within is the input. I am able to override the text of this specific input by doing this

```
MuiInput: {
      root: {
        color: "#eee",
      },
    },
```

Results would be that I am able to modify the focused color for the search and the default unfocused color of the input line.

This is where I need to style:

[image: This is where I need to style]

Answer (score 0):

As stated from this Github [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11244), you can add another property to the object:

```
   "&$focused": { 
      color: "blue"
    }
```

Another option would be to determine the native classes attached to the MuiInput, and setting your own CSS rules with `!important`.